# prism composing same module multiple times

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, prism

I am developing an application with multiple modules (User, Project, Payment, Invoice, etc). Each of these modules has a reference to a common module that contains shared controls named App.Controls. App.Controls contains a view called OKSaveDialogView which is just a shell view with Ok/Save buttons and some common functionality. OKSaveDialogView loads the appropriate content dynamically for resuability. Unfortunately the App.Controls part is being loaded into the catalog multiple times causing the error:

1) More than one export was found that matches the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == "App.Controls.ViewModels.OkCancelDialogViewModel")

I am not sure where to even begin debugging how this is happening. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Below are some code snips from the project:

OKCaneclDialogView.Xaml.VB

```
<Export("OkCancelDialogView")> _
<PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)> _
Partial Public Class OkCancelDialogView
    Inherits UserControl

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    <Import()> _
    Public Property ViewModel() As OkCancelDialogViewModel
        Get
            Return Me.DataContext
        End Get
        Set(value As OkCancelDialogViewModel)
            Me.DataContext = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

OkCancelDialoViewModel.vb

```
<Export()> _
<PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)> _
Public Class OkCancelDialogViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase
    Implements INavigationAware
    Implements IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
    'Implements IOkCancelDialogViewModel


    'Services
    'Private ReadOnly regionManager As IRegionManager
    Private WithEvents userService As IUserDataService

    Private navigationJournal As IRegionNavigationJournal

    Private Const UserIdKey As String = "PrimaryId"
    Private Const SecondaryIdKey As String = "SecondaryId"
    Private Const DialogContentKey As String = "DialogContent"

    'DialogViewModelDictionary
    Private DialogViewModelDictionary As DialogViewModelDictionaries

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(New RegionManager)
    End Sub

    <ImportingConstructor()> _
    Public Sub New(regionManager As IRegionManager)
        'Setup the global region manager
        Me.RegionManager = regionManager

        'Setup the locally scoped region manager
        Me.LocalRegionManager = regionManager.CreateRegionManager

        Me.synchronizationContext = If(synchronizationContext.Current, New SynchronizationContext())

        'Setup commands
        Me._closeCommand = New DelegateCommand(AddressOf OnClose)

        Me._okSaveCommand = New DelegateCommand(AddressOf Me.OnOkSave, AddressOf Me.CanClickOkSave)
        Me._CancelCommand = New DelegateCommand(AddressOf Me.OnCancel, AddressOf Me.CanClickCancel)


        DialogViewModelDictionary = New DialogViewModelDictionaries
        DialogViewModelDictionary.AddDialogViewModel("EditAddressDialogView", New EditAddressDialogViewModel())
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you turned off `copy local` on the references to App.Controls in User, Project, Payment & Invoice? It should only be referenced (with copy local) in the main app so that it is loaded once at startup.